# unexpected end of file laravel blade , sql injection

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

hi so im trying to do a simple redirection and this is the code :

```
<div class="search">
    {{ Form::open(array('url' => 'search', 'class' => 'form-horizontal')) }}
    {{ Form::text('username', null, array( 'placeholder' => 'Search query...' )) }}
    @if(null !==Form::submit('Search'))
    Redirect('result')
    {{Form::close()}}
</div>
```

but its giving me :

> syntax error, unexpected end of file

I want to know if my search  code has flaws or any sql injection :

```
$keyword = Input::get('username');
$users = User::where ('username','LIKE','%'.$keyword.'%')->get();
foreach($users as $user)
{
    $rock =  ($user->username);
}
```

Comment: Missing an `@endif`? Might want to check the [template documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/templates).

Comment: SQL injection will be no problem. Laravel takes care of that. However you can't make a redirect like that. It looks more like you are looking for a javascript solution. Although I don't know exactly what you're trying to do...

Comment: @endif cleared my error 
lukas , after submitting the search buttom i want my users to redirect to some other page with the results
now it giving me the error : Call to undefined function redirect()

Comment: you're missing a } somewhere probably.

Comment: Please read the docs on how Laravel forms work. They just generate HTML. `Form::submit('Search')` will generate the HTML for a submit button. You can't use it to handle the submit event.

Comment: so how should i do what i intended ?

Comment: Laravel uses the MVC approach. It's pretty straightforward when you understand it. You generate and submit the form from the **V**iew, you handle the form submission on the **C**ontroller and update your database via the **M**odel. The documentation is a little strange, but it does provide the information you need to solve this.

Comment: yes documentation is kindaa BAD for a beginner like me its like the gave it to their laziest employee to write it , some sections has 1 line description for it , thanks for you reply ;)